# Robust regression vs bootstrapping of confidence intervals

Tags: multiple-regression, bootstrap, robust

In multiple regression, when the independent variable is not normally distributed and the dependent variable is not normally distributed, is bootstrapping of the confidence intervals or robust regression first choice? 
Is there any advantage of bootstrapping of confidence intervals if the independent variable is normally distributed but not the dependent variable?
Is there any publication explaining the difference between the methods?

Comment: In regression, we don't care about the distribution of the independent or dependent variables, we only care about the distribution of the error term - and even that only somewhat.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to our site! But your question is very broad and unclear, see below.

In regression, we do not care about the *marginal* distributions of neither the dependent nor predictor variables. We care about the *conditional* distribution of the dependent variable (given the regressors), that is, of the *error term*.  In regression models we *condition on $x$*, that is, we take the predictor variables $x$ as given, deterministic. Regression models do not care about their distribution, at least not very much.

Apart from that, you would be better off asking your real question. What kind of data do you have? What is the goal? Maybe present some plots, and some of your preliminary analysis. First then can we see if you need bootstrapping, or robust regression, or something entirely else!